# How to deploy Angular Universal project to standard hosting?

Tags: deployment, web-hosting, angular-universal

I have my Angular Universal project working on my localhost. So now I would like to test it on my standard web hosting with Node.js installed.

I have run:

```
npm run build
```

and received *dist* folder with *client* and *server* subfolders.

How should I use these folders and files into them to run the project on the hosting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have deployed my Angular Universal project to my hosting.

I can say that the support team of my hosting gave me a lot of help. I don't know if is it possible to deploy such project on the own.

My hosting has a Node.js support. Support team of the hosting gave me an instruction how to install Node.js on the hosting using *terminal* on
    Mac or programs for Windows like *PuTTY*.

Then I walked through the following steps:

1. Create the folder for the project on the hosting.
2. Copy the *dist* folder to created folder.
3. Install NPM in the project folder. At this step support team gave me some help. Because you should do something with PATH to
   proper install and work of NPM.
4. Standard hosting links the *public_html* folder to your domain name. But Angular Universal project should be in a separate folder.
   So I have asked the support to redirect my domain to the Angular
   project folder and proper port.
5. Run server using terminal:

> node dist/server/server.js

After all I can see my project working good on my domain name.

**Addition.** Also I tried the following way: copied my project folder (without *node_modules* folder) to the hosting and then run

> npm install
>
> npm run build

You can create the *dist* folder on the hosting also by these commands.

**Addition.** Assume that you config your Node.js server on your hosting. Also you should make shure that your project ready to be deployed. Here is a link what code needs to prepair this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering

You also need to copy on your hosting your **client/** and **server/** folders and also **server.js** and **package.json** files. 
Then you can run your application by

> node server.js

Comment: What hosting provider do you use?

Comment: I used Beget.com. The project was deployed, however there was a problem with working with data. On my local machine the project worked perfectly but after deployment I could see the front-client but no data was loading, I tried something but couldn't solve the issue. As it was my testing efforts I didn't go futher.

Comment: @Kirill Ch can u share your website Url link here and if you now know all that steps means explain again or any reference url

Comment: @chozharajan Sorry, I now don't use Angular Universal any more as I create only corporate systems where Universal and its page rendering is unnecessary.

Comment: @KirilCh I am getting client and server folder in dist folder. How to proceed further procedure. Please tell step by steps

Comment: @KirilCh pls provide more information.Me also struggling on this

Comment: @kamalav Good day. I haven't use Universal for a long time now. When I deployed my project - the support team gave my a lot of help, some features they config by themselves as I told in the answer. Other steps I think are clearly described in the answer, they are not very difficult. Also see my addition about preparation the project to proper deploy.

Comment: @KirillCh where do you host your website? and how much you pay per month? It is not a shared server right? Because I host on bluehost on a shared server, and they told me that it does not support NodeJs. So in other words, I am not able to deploy my "universal build" on it!!

Comment: @EddyG ye, I see. I used standard hosting and provider with Node.js support. It seems major providers give such option and technical help if nesessary. At any case you can get an instruction how to use your Node.js at them. My provider is Russian (as I am) - Beget.com. I use simple standard service package it is about 5$ per month.

Comment: @KirillCh Thanks for sharing. I host on bluehost which is popular, but doesn't support Node.js on standard hosting plans!! But, I found a solution that makes a static rendering without requiring Node.js, by posting a question here, check it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56515353/deploy-angular-rendered-app-on-shared-server/56515485#56515485